# Delete rows with multiple criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

my goal is to delete rows with column 3 with the cell value that has inventory (>0) and column 4 that has the cell value TRUE in the current sheet. I tried to use the code to this website and I'm pretty sure I did something wrong where it says `ActiveSheet.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete`

```
Public Sub FilterStock()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="TRUE"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveSheet.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: `DataBodyRange` is the property of a `ListObject`... not a `Worksheet`.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
Sub DeletelRows()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim debug1 As Variant
    Dim debug2 As Variant

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column C
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = lastRow To 2 Step -1  'Start at bottom and go up to avoid complications when the row is deleted.

        debug1 = Cells(x, 3).Value  'You can set breakpoints to see what the values are.
        debug2 = Cells(x, 4).Value

        If (Cells(x, 3).Value > 0 And UCase(Cells(x, 4).Value) = "TRUE") Then
            Rows(x).Delete
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```